# Joining two columns with filtering by ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to join two columns from my database, and filter by postID so that I can use URL parameter postid. The code below doesn't work, but I don't know how to change it. Suggestions?

```
$colname_join = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['postID'])) {
  $colname_join = $_GET['postID'];
}

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_join = sprintf("SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.postimage = image.imagename WHERE postID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_join, "int"));
$join = mysql_query($query_join, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_join = mysql_fetch_assoc($join);
$totalRows_join = mysql_num_rows($join);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql  = "SELECT *
        FROM image
        INNER JOIN post ON post.postimage = image.imagename
        WHERE postID = %s". GetSQLValueString($colname_join, "int")";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to read that article : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

The selected answer shows you how to make a query with variable parts, and safe from sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have wrong column name `postID` in sql query:

```
$query_join = sprintf("SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.postimage = image.imagename WHERE postID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_join, "int"));
```

Change it to right column name that is present in table `post`, for example, if it's `post.id` column:

```
$query_join = sprintf("SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.postimage = image.imagename WHERE post.id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_join, "int"));
```